# Is autolayout buggy?

Tags: swift, autolayout

I have some problems with autolayout, and I am beginning to wonder if there are bugs in there. I have more issues, but this one seems very clear to me. Constraints are built by code, so I can show only screeshots from View hierarchy debugger.

Setup is easy - KeyboardView as parent, and inside four UILayoutGuides making margins at borders. There is of course more of it, but this should be enough for the issue. When app starts, everything is ok. But after some activating and deactivating groups of constraints by code, I end with this (no error in constraints is reported, layout just breaks silently)

Here is view debugger focused on the KeyboardView (it is the green one). It has a width of 414, which is correct, and is a result of autolayout constraints pinning its sides to superview.
[image]

But when I highlight one of LayoutGuides, I see this:
[image]

Layout guide has active constraint pinning its trailing edge to the trailing edge of superview (which is the KeyboardView). So it should be inside the green area, at the right edge. But it is totally out! Even if you look at frame, X is at 432.67, which is clearly outside its 414 parent. So the resulting frame constradicts the constraints, but system does not report any problem. I get NOTHING about contradicting constraints and need to break them. Even breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints symbol does not fire. Layout just silently breaks without any reason.

Has anyone ever encountered such problems?

Comment: As a general rule, no, auto-layout is not buggy. It's difficult to tell what might be going on without seeing more information. For example, your screen-cap shows your Layout Guide horizontally constrained to `DistributionView` -- but where is that? It also looks like you're adding a whole lot of unnecessary layout elements. Is there a reason you're not using stack views to manage the buttons "grid"?

Comment: DistributionView is the inner grey one, and it is pinned between the four margin spacers. Generally, whole layout is designed from the outside in, so the child should always take size from parent, and not otherwise.

Comment: I see that there is too many things going on in my views. But my question is - how is it possible, that the resulting frame of a view (well, UILayoutGuide) contradicts on of its constraints, which is still active and never was reported as broken? As I understand it, it should never happen; if there is a conflict between constraints, it should be reported and one of the constraints should be broken (and shown grayed out in view hierarchy debugger).

Comment: @DonMag As for StackView - sometimes I need button to spread over multiple rows or cols. Keyboard is not always such a nice matrix. I believe that StackView does not give enough control over that.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I seem to find the problem, and it seems like a bug in autolayout to me. Problem was the grid of spacers (UILayoutGuides) between buttons in the keyboard. Their X and Y centers were positioned to parent's trailing and bottom edges with multiplier - in order to put them at the exact percentage of parent's width or height. Such constraint can't be done with anchors api (cant' use centerXAnchor with multiplier), but is perfectly valid constraint and can be made directly with NSLayoutConstraint() constructor.

These constraints usually work as they are supposed to, but under sume circumstances, after multiple activating and deactivating groups of constraints, they can break autolayout in a very weird way. Like the one that I asked about.

I resolved the problem by using helper UILayoutGuides (yes, even more of them :-/ ) that match its parent's width or height with multiplier. Which is OK; while position with multiplier makes problems, size with multiplier is OK. Then I used trailing and top edges of these helper to pin centers of my spacers to. Such construction now does work perfectly.